# Heuristic rules for CriticalSection[]

Tags: parallelization

I am new to concurrent programming. While parallelizing a Do loop with ParallelDo, I found some rules to obey to program more easily. Could you please check whether these rules are correct in most cases? I am especially unsure concerning the validity of Rules 2, 5 and 7.

1. Use local variables where possible with as minimal scope as possible.  (to prevent being overwritten by another kernel) That is: Combine, for example, ParallelDo[] with Block[] to protect variables, which are created during an iteration and are no iterators, from being accessed by other kernels.
2. If you can choose concerning a small task (e. g. a progress bar) between "let the kernels speak with each other" and "let the main kernel do it", choose the main kernel. (Easier to debug)
3. To avoid reoccuring errors, run DistributeFunctions[...] after every function redefinition for all dependent functions. (i. e., the changed function and functions which call the changed function)
4. CriticalSection[] is permitted to exist within ParallelDo.
5. Sometimes, critical sections should overlap, which is not possible due to the necessary validity of the braces. For example, `CriticalSection[M1, <quelltext1> CriticalSection(<quelltext2>]<quelltext3>)` is not permitted.) Then type `CriticalSection[M1, <quelltext1> CriticalSection(<quelltext2><quelltext3>)]`, you have to hazard the consequences of an unnecessary large variable lock.
6. Iteration variables seem to be shared variables, so manipulate them with great care.
7. There occur no additional errors in nearly all practical applications, if we have too many / large CriticalSections.
8. Local variables, which are not changed in the following parallel constructs (e. g. `Block[{x}, x = 5; ParallelDo[y = 10, {k, 10}]]`) do not need to be protected with a CriticalSection[].

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Could you please add a link to the source of this text? Adding a concrete problem statement with an example would get more focused replies. A general (and/or an opinionated) discussion is not recommended on stack sites. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have written the text myself. I will work on a concrete, yet short, example. I hope that the rules are clearly false or right in all practical cases, hence a discussion should be unnecessary due to only one correct way to do it.